# Фильтр по дате во временной таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Присутствует примерно следующий запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE #Productr (date_time date, id varchar(50), type varchar(50));
INSERT INTO #Productr VALUES
('2020-07-01',    '11',    'PC'),
('2021-02-09',    '11',    'Printer'),
('2019-01-29',    '22',    'Phone'),
('2018-03-14',    '22',    'Charger'),
('2020-04-19',    '22',    'Phone');
 
 --select * from #Productr
 --drop table #Productr
```

Подскажите, каким образом я могу с помощью временной таблицы   достать заявки, кроме последних по дате?
Что хочу получить на выходе:

```
date_time   id  type
2020-07-01  11  PC
2019-01-29  22  Phone
2018-03-14  22  Charger
```

Comment: `... where d < (select max(d) from ...)`

Comment: Извините , смогу ли я таким образом приджойнить к исходной ?

Comment: не ясно, что такое у вас исходная. опишите задачу более конкретно. также не ясно, что вы называете "кроме последней" ибо в тестовых данных 5 строк за разные даты, в желаемом результате только 3. То есть отфильтрована не только самая последняя дата имеющаяся

Comment: Для 11 id - последняя по дате запись - '2021-02-09'. Для 22 id - '2020-04-19'. Как мне не учитывать записи по этим id?

Comment: ааа.. в таком смысле. несколько путей есть. первый - джойн с `select id, max(d) ,,,`  . Второй - нумерация строк `row_number() over( partition by id order date_time desc)` и последующая фильтрация `>=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

исходные

```
declare @t table (d date, id varchar(50), t varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    ('2020-07-01',    '11',    'PC'),
    ('2021-02-09',    '11',    'Printer'),
    ('2019-01-29',    '22',    'Phone'),
    ('2018-03-14',    '22',    'Charger'),
    ('2020-04-19',    '22',    'Phone');
```

Способ первый - найти максимальные даты товаров, сделать джойн с условием, что  нужна дата меньше максимальной.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM @t as t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, max(d) AS d
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY id
) AS m ON ( m.id = t.id and t.d < m.d )
```

Способ второй - пронумеровать все строки по убыванию даты в группах для каждого товара. Исключить строки с первым номером из выборки

```
WITH x AS (
    select d, id, t, row_number() over (partition by id order by d desc) as rn
    from @t
)
SELECT d, id, t
FROM x
WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: загвоздка будет, если есть только одна запись по продукту. она же будет максимальной. соответственно отсеется в обоих случаях. В общем вектор решения такой. но надо доработать.

Comment: в первом случае, например, помимо `max(d)` можно посчитать `count(id)`  и добавить условие `OR c = 1`

Comment: хотя `count(id)` плохой вариант. может быть несколько записей за единственный день. тогда count будет больше 1, а дата все равно одна

Comment: Подскажите, а если формат даты с минутами и секундами, то можно использовать count ?

Comment: @АрсенийКоролев вы лучше объясните, какую ситуацию хотите отфильтровать, помимо того. что содержится в самом ответе.

Comment: Есть основная таблтца , в ней находятся id и номера товаров, дата. К ней нужно добавить столбец , который будет заполнен 1, если на один и тот же товар(до момента последней заявки) была сделана заявка от другого id. И 0, если этот товар еще не был заказан никаким id или был только у id.
Как раз что бы достать заявки после последней, я и задал изначальный вопрос. Сейчас меня интересует ваш коментарий по поводу 2 заявок одним клиентом в один день. Если формат даты вкулючает себя секунды и минуты, мне не стоит опасаться проблем, связанных с вашим способом в котором используется count(id) ?

Comment: чтобы узнать, заказывал ли кто-то товар кроме последнего "клиента", достаточно просто посчитать число уникальных "клиентов" для каждого товара. Если оно (`count(distinct клиент_ид)`) будет больше 1, то очевидно, были и другие покупатели. Для этого не нужно как-то выделять последнюю покупку и т.п.